# Injection of EJB3 into Annotation Based JSF2 Backing bean causing javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, ejb-3.0, websphere-7

I have seen other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295514/jsf2-managed-bean-annotation-scope-injection-confusion) with similar issue but was not able to work out direct link with my problem . Hopefully I am not repeating a question.My issue is this: 
I am using Webpsphere 7 with JSF2 as Shared Isolated Library .
When I try to inject an EJB3 into in  an annotated JSF2 backing bean I get this error

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name comp/env/helloworld.HelloBean not found in context "java:".
```

but It works fine if we configure JSF2 using face.xml and not use annotation. However without EJB3 injection we can use the application with JSF2 annotations and not see any issue only when we try to inject ejb3 we get issues. Code from a simple trial app is below

Service interface:

```
package au.com.test;

import javax.ejb.Local;

@Local
public interface SampleService {
    public String getServiceName();
}
```

Service Implementation:

```
package au.com.test;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;


@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute (TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public class SampleSession implements SampleService {

    @Override
    public String getServiceName() {
        return "Sample Service";
    }

}
```

JSF managed bean:

```
package helloworld;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import au.com.example.service.SampleService;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class HelloBean implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;    

    @EJB
    private SampleService sampleService;


    public String getName() {       
        return  sampleService.getServiceName()+ name;       
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

The Stack trace is below

```
[2/08/11 7:52:20:394 EST] 00000034 HtmlImageRend W   ALT attribute is missing for : waveImg
[2/08/11 7:52:20:488 EST] 00000034 FaceletViewDe E   Error Rendering View[/hello.xhtml]
                                 javax.faces.FacesException: Could not retrieve value of component with path : {Component-Path : [Class: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /hello.xhtml][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlBody,Id: j_id327415688_1383f7c7][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm,Id: helloForm][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText,Id: username]}
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.getValue(RendererUtils.java:347)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.getStringValue(RendererUtils.java:291)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlTextRendererBase.renderInputBegin(HtmlTextRendererBase.java:169)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlTextRendererBase.renderInput(HtmlTextRendererBase.java:158)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlTextRendererBase.encodeEnd(HtmlTextRendererBase.java:75)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:519)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:672)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:668)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:668)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:668)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1483)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:281)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:85)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:239)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:353)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:784)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3933)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name comp/env/helloworld.HelloBean not found in context "java:".
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.ManagedBeanBuilder.buildManagedBean(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:225)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.ManagedBeanResolver.createManagedBean(ManagedBeanResolver.java:332)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.ManagedBeanResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanResolver.java:295)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:143)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:142)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.VariableResolverImpl.resolveVariable(VariableResolverImpl.java:65)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.convert.VariableResolverToELResolver.getValue(VariableResolverToELResolver.java:116)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:143)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:142)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:45)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:91)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:263)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:85)
    at javax.faces.component._DeltaStateHelper.eval(_DeltaStateHelper.java:246)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:71)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:142)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.getValue(RendererUtils.java:343)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name comp/env/helloworld.HelloBean not found in context "java:".
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.getParentCtxInternal(NameSpace.java:1837)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookupInternal(NameSpace.java:1166)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookup(NameSpace.java:1095)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextImpl.lookup(UrlContextImpl.java:1233)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.lookup(javaURLContextImpl.java:395)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:154)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.ResourceAnnotationLifecycleProvider.lookupFieldResource(ResourceAnnotationLifecycleProvider.java:127)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.AllAnnotationLifecycleProvider.checkFieldAnnotation(AllAnnotationLifecycleProvider.java:83)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.ResourceAnnotationLifecycleProvider.checkAnnotation(ResourceAnnotationLifecycleProvider.java:78)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.ResourceAnnotationLifecycleProvider.processAnnotations(ResourceAnnotationLifecycleProvider.java:55)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.NoInjectionAnnotationLifecycleProvider.newInstance(NoInjectionAnnotationLifecycleProvider.java:46)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.ManagedBeanBuilder.buildManagedBean(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:155)
    ... 55 more

[2/08/11 7:52:20:503 EST] 00000034 ErrorPageWrit E   An exception occurred
                                 javax.faces.FacesException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name comp/env/helloworld.HelloBean not found in context "java:".
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.wrap(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:241)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:156)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:258)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:353)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:784)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3933)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name comp/env/helloworld.HelloBean not found in context "java:".
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.getParentCtxInternal(NameSpace.java:1837)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookupInternal(NameSpace.java:1166)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookup(NameSpace.java:1095)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextImpl.lookup(UrlContextImpl.java:1233)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.lookup(javaURLContextImpl.java:395)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:154)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.ResourceAnnotationLifecycleProvider.lookupFieldResource(ResourceAnnotationLifecycleProvider.java:127)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.AllAnnotationLifecycleProvider.checkFieldAnnotation(AllAnnotationLifecycleProvider.java:83)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.ResourceAnnotationLifecycleProvider.checkAnnotation(ResourceAnnotationLifecycleProvider.java:78)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.ResourceAnnotationLifecycleProvider.processAnnotations(ResourceAnnotationLifecycleProvider.java:55)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.NoInjectionAnnotationLifecycleProvider.newInstance(NoInjectionAnnotationLifecycleProvider.java:46)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.ManagedBeanBuilder.buildManagedBean(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:155)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.ManagedBeanResolver.createManagedBean(ManagedBeanResolver.java:332)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.ManagedBeanResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanResolver.java:295)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:143)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:142)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.VariableResolverImpl.resolveVariable(VariableResolverImpl.java:65)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.convert.VariableResolverToELResolver.getValue(VariableResolverToELResolver.java:116)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:143)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:142)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:45)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:91)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:263)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:85)
    at javax.faces.component._DeltaStateHelper.eval(_DeltaStateHelper.java:246)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:71)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:142)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.getValue(RendererUtils.java:343)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.getStringValue(RendererUtils.java:291)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlTextRendererBase.renderInputBegin(HtmlTextRendererBase.java:169)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlTextRendererBase.renderInput(HtmlTextRendererBase.java:158)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlTextRendererBase.encodeEnd(HtmlTextRendererBase.java:75)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:519)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:672)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:668)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:668)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:668)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1483)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:281)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:85)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:239)
    ... 26 more
```

Can any one help me with this .

**UPDATE**
These are two separate modules sitting inside an EAR which gets deployed WAS7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shared libraries are not considered for locating component-defining annotations (like @ManagedBean), so the component is not found, which means its @EJB is not found while building the java:comp namespace.  Your options are:

1. Mention the JSF bean in faces-config.xml in the WAR.
2. Place the JSF bean in the WAR.
3. Define the <ejb-ref> in web.xml.
4. Define the ejb-ref with annotations in a dummy "resource producer" bean in the WAR.

For #4, an example would be:

```
@ManagedBean
@EJBs({
   @EJB(name="helloworld.HelloBean", type=SampleService.class)
   // ... etc
})
public class ResourceProducerBean { }
```

Comment: Thanks Bkail. 1 and 3 work . Checking 4 but for 2 and 4 can you please example what you mean by in the WAR e.g HelloBean is a jsf backing bean and sitting at C:\..\ibm\..\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\was70profile1\installedApps\myMachineNode01Cell\My_Application.ear\My_Web.war\WEB-INF\classes\helloworld as HelloBean.class.

Comment: Also what would be the lifecycle of dummy bean if I choose option 4 would be bloated or would there be a performance impact if one bean loads all ejbs. Option 4 looks cleanest but have these concerns also as above not sure about what you meant bt in the war file. Thanks

Comment: There is some JSF MB that has an @EJB annotation.  For #2, I mean place that JSF MB in the WAR so that the annotation scanner can see it.

Comment: For #4, if the bean is never instantiated, then the only overhead will be minimal when the class is scanned at deploy time for annotations.  If the approach works, the ejb-ref will be merged into c:\...\was70profile1\config\cells\${cell}\applications\${app}.ear\deployments\${app}\${module}.war\WEB-INF\web_merged.xml.